How to set an attribute on a type parameter?
How do I set an attribute on a type parameter in VB? Or in other words, how do I translate the following C# code into valid VB?
public static void Method2<[DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicMethods)] T>() {
    Type t = typeof(T);
    Method3(t);
}

I tried the following two things, but none would compile:
Public Shared Sub Method2(Of <DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicMethods)>T)()
    Dim type As Type = GetType(T)
    Method3(type)
End Sub

and
Public Shared Sub Method2(<DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicMethods)> Of T)()
    Dim type As Type = GetType(T)
    Method3(type)
End Sub


There is no VB equivalent. I think this is a newer C# feature and VB language syntax changes ended around 2015.

You can load the VB.Net DLLs in ILSpy and output them as C# projects.
